# Angular 4 Animations add parameters

Tags: angular, animation

Here is a random animation I've made

```
    import { trigger, animate, transition, style, keyframes} from '@angular/animations';

    export const customAnimation=
        trigger('customAnimation', [
            transition(':leave', [
                style({position: 'relative'}),
                animate("250ms ease-in", keyframes([
                    style({top: 0}),
                    style({top: -300}),
                ]))
            ])
        ])
```

I am then importing it into my components. (`animations: [customAnimation]`
)
However, I'd like to use the new arguments features :
(http://sudheerjonna.com/blog/2017/06/30/angular-4-2-release-an-improved-version-for-animation-package/).

By instance, the -300 would become a parameter, and I would call it on me template elements by doing :

```
<div [@customAnimation]="{pixels: -300}">
```

Since I don't want to use `animation()` and `useAnimation()` as I want to use on specific dom element (not using a `query()` either) I simply didn't manage to do it.

**EDIT:**

Got it working with :

```
export const leavingTowardsTop=
    trigger('leavingTowardsTop', [
        transition(':leave', [
            style({position: 'relative'}),
            animate("250ms ease-in", keyframes([
                style({top: 0}),
                style({top: "{{pixels}}"})
            ]))
        ], {params : { pixels: "-30px" }})
    ])
```

only issue, I can't specify another value than the default one (-30). I tried :

```
[@leavingTowardsTop]="{params : { pixels: '-300px' }}"
```

and

```
[@leavingTowardsTop]="{ pixels: '-300px' }"
```

I also tried not specifying the `'` or `px` but it still takes 30px

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the solution I needed

```
[@leavingTowardsTop]="{value: ':leave', params : {topPixels: '-300px'}}"
```

Comment: is this syntax documented anywhere? what does this look live if there are several transitions to provide values for?

Comment: can you explain what 'value' means? are you selecting a state? overriding parameters for a particular state? and what if you had more than just one.

Comment: One thing to note, store the object in a class variable, it doesn't seem to update if you just change a property, you have to reassign a new object reference

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: `value` is the “trigger value” of the simpler parameterless form: `[@someAnim]="foo"` => `[@someAnim]="{value: 'foo', params: {...}}"`

Comment: Like @Sam I am also looking for an documentation. An interface would be great.

Answer (score 21):

You need to parameterize the `top` style like so:

```
export const customAnimation=
    trigger('customAnimation', [
        transition(':leave', [
            animate("500ms ease-in", keyframes([
                style({'margin-top': "-{{pixels}}px", 'height': "{{pixels}}px", 'margin-bottom': "0px"}),
            ]))
        ], {params : { pixels: "30" }})
    ]);
```

Then call it in the view like so:

```
[@customAnimation]="{value: ':leave', params: { pixels: 100}}"
```

## [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/osCcZnfvPKHMVdSIegHK?p=preview)

Comment: can I add a default value ?